# Dynamically scale SVG image to the frame/window size

Tags: java, swing, svg, java-7

I am using SVGSalamander.
My code loads a svg image and sets it as background of a `JDesktopPane`.

```
File f = new File("awesome_tiger.svg");
SVGUniverse svgUniverse = new SVGUniverse();
try {
  SVGDiagram diagram = svgUniverse.getDiagram(svgUniverse.loadSVG(f.toURL()));
  try {
    diagram.render(g);
  }
  catch(Exception ex) {System.out.println(ex);}}
catch (Exception ex2) {System.out.println(ex2);}
```

How can I achieve, that the image fills the window/frame completely and resizes with it?

Seems SVGSalamander has the method `isScaleToFit()` but how can I use it?

I use for `antiAlias` this: `g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);` (this is how it is written in the SVGIcon and SVGPanel classes)

**Edit:** solved it

```
AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
at.setToScale(jdpPane.getWidth()/diagram.getWidth(), jdpPane.getWidth()/diagram.getWidth());
g.transform(at);
diagram.render(g);
```

scales it proportionally

Comment: I tried this, I got one problem is, our internal frames are also Scaling, Please help me to solve it

Comment: Please open a new question with your code and describe your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use an `AffineTransform` and the `setToScale` method

```
File f = new File("awesome_tiger.svg");
g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
SVGUniverse svgUniverse = new SVGUniverse();
try {
  SVGDiagram diagram = svgUniverse.getDiagram(svgUniverse.loadSVG(f.toURI().toURL()));
  try {
    AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
    at.setToScale(jdpPane.getWidth()/diagram.getWidth(), jdpPane.getWidth()/diagram.getWidth());
    g.transform(at);
    diagram.render(g);
  }
  catch(Exception e2) {System.out.println(e2);}}
catch (Exception ex) {System.out.println(ex);}
```

this is the code with which I am overriding the `paint()` method